# Error al agregar componentes universales de Windows en visual en cuadro de herramientas de visual studio 2022

Tags: windows-forms, formularios, windows

Estoy intentando agregar el componente serialport en el cuadro de herramientas de visual studio pero al cargar la ventana de elegir elementos del cuadro de herramientas en la pestaña de componentes universales de Windows me arroja el siguiente error: "error en el rellenado de pestañas debido a una excepción: su se carga este ensamblado, se generará un conjunto de permisos diferentes de otras instancias. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131401)."

El programa que estoy desarrollando es con Windows forms y estoy utilizando la version 2022 17.7.4 de visual studio

Probé actualizar visual studio,
Iniciar Visual Studio como administrador,
Cambiar la version de .NET,
Agregar caracteristicas adicionales en el visual studio installer.

Comment: Estoy utilizando visual studio 2022 e su versión 17.7.4 y en el cuadro de herramientas no me aparece el objeto serialport, intente agregarlo haciendo clic derecho sobre el cuadro de herramientas y haciendo clic donde dice elegir elementos del cuadro de herramientas, una vez allí supuse que la opción estaría en la pestaña de componentes universales de Windows, pero me arroja el error ya mencionado, de casualidad saben como solucionarlo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si tenes que agregar mas informacion, usa el boton [edit]